# Add Macro to Excel file from R

Tags: r, excel, vba, rdcomclient

I am using `RDCOMClient` package in R. I am able to run existing Macro in Excel Workbook from R. Is there a simple way to add a Macro to Excel Workbook, when it is written in asimple `.txt` file?

So far I have:

```
    library(RDCOMClient)
    xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
    xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(normalizePath(list.files(pattern=".xlsm")[1])) 
    ### open first xlsm file in working directory
    xlApp$Run("Send") ## Run existing Macro named "Send"
```

Can i do something like `xlApp$AddMacro("myMacro.txt")` to add new Macro to the workbook?

**EDIT:** I managed to add empty module and name it, but somehow I cannot add the code to it:

```
mo <- xlApp$Modules()$Add()
mo[["Name"]] <- "Test"
smth like mo[["Body??"]]
```

Comment: Covered in depth here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx  Should be adaptable to R/COM

Comment: Can you help me insert the code to the module? I went through procedure desribed on the page but it doesnt seem to wrok.  @TimWilliams

Comment: It would be much easier to export the module containing the macro from Excel as a *.bas file, and then import that.

Comment: ...from the link I posted:  `ToVBProject.VBComponents.Import Filename:=FName`

Comment: I also would like an answer to this question. I have R write a macro, and if I add that macro manually to a master macro workbook, I can open both the master macro workbook, and the workbook I need edited. Then I can use the macros. But I need a way to have R add the macros to the master workbook. The document you linked is really long, made for a different programming language, and difficult to understand.

Comment: @Frank Probably best to open new question, this one is old an noone is looking into it anymore.